# Issues augmenting Material UI v5 Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tabs

I'm trying to augment the indicator colors of Tabs in MaterialUI v5.

I have this declaration file:

**mui.d.ts**

```
interface PaletteColor {
    light?: string;
    main: string;
    dark?: string;
    contrastText?: string;
}

export interface Colors {
    green: true;
    lightgreen: true;
    blue: true;
    lightblue: true;
    black: true;
    darkgrey: true;
    lightgrey: true;
    beige: true;
    cream: true;
    white: true;
}

type CustomColorsPalette = {
    [K in keyof Colors]: PaletteColor;
};

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Palette extends CustomColorsPalette {}
    interface PaletteOptions extends CustomColorsPalette {}
}

declare module '@mui/material/Tabs' {
    interface TabsPropsIndicatorColorOverrides extends Colors {}
}
```

And this theme file:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        green: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#ffffff',
        },
        lightgreen: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        blue: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        lightblue: {
            main: '#75bfc7',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        black: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        darkgrey: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        lightgrey: {
            main: '#dcdcd3',
            contrastText: '#...',
        },
        beige: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        cream: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        white: {
            main: '#...',
            contrastText: '#000000',
        },
        contrastThreshold: 3,
        tonalOffset: 0.2,
    },
});
```

Then 'lightblue' does show up in the **indicatorColor** property on the **Tabs** component as such:

```
//...
<Tabs
          variant="scrollable"
          value={value}
          onChange={...}
          aria-label="..."
          indicatorColor='lightblue'
        >
//...
```

However the indicator color does not show up. Any idea how we can fix this using module augmentation?